# Diagonalizing a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

I have the quadratic form
$$Q(x)=x_1^2+2x_1x_4+x_2^2 +2x_2x_3+2x_3^2+2x_3x_4+2x_4^2$$

I want to diagonalize the matrix of $Q$. I know I need to find the matrix of the associated bilinear form but I am unsure on how to do this.

Comment: You want to diagonalise the matrix of $Q$ or write $Q$ as the sum of squares of linear forms?

Comment: @Bernard diagonalise the matrix of Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the associated matrix $A = (a_{ij})$.

Then, simply apply this:

1. $a_{ii} = c$ where c is the coefficient of $x_i^2$
2. $a_{ij} = \frac c 2$ where c is the coefficient of $x_ix_j$

So, your matrix will be

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&1&2&1\\
1&0&1&2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Leonhard can you diagonalise it or should I show you that?

Comment: Do I find the unit eigenvectors of A and set them as the columns of a matrix?

Comment: @Leonhard yeah that's it

Answer (score 2):

It is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&1&2&1\\
1&0&1&2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

*Some details*

The diagonal coefficients are the coefficients of the squares. The $(i,j)$ and the $(j,i)$ coefficient are  half the coefficient of the $x_ix_j$ monomial. This results from the reverse computation of the quadratic form associated to a symmetric matrix $(a_{ij})$.

Comment: Could you add some detail as to how you got it? The method is more important to than the answer as I want to know how to do it for other cases.

Comment: As you have 4 variables your matrix $Q$ will be 4x4. 
The coefficient $(i,j)$ of your matrix will be the coefficient associated to the term $x_i x_j$. For example $(q_{11})=1$ and $(q_{14})=2$. This way you can construct the matrix $Q$

Comment: @Leonhard Written in matrix form, $Q$ is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)M(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T$ for some symmetric matrix $M$. If you multiply this out and compare it to $Q$, you’ll see that the diagonal elements are the coefficients of $x_i^2$ and that the off-diagonal elements are the coefficients of $x_ix_j$ (divided by two, usually, since $x_ix_j$ and $x_jx_i$ will likely have been combined into a single term $Q$).